# How to make `local` capture the exit code?

Tags: bash, variable, exit-status

In my project I have the following snippet:

```
local output="$(bash "${1##*/}")"
echo "$?"
```

This always prints zero due to `local`, however, removing `local` causes the `$?` variable to behave correctly: which is to assume the exit code from the subshell.

My question is: how I can keep this variable local whilst also capturing the exit value?

Comment: [`shellcheck`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) will not only catch this issue but suggest the solution at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281749/24718!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
thing() {
   local foo=$(asjkdh) ret="$?"
   echo "$ret"
}
```

This will echo `127`, the correct error code for "command not found".

You can use `local` to define more than one variable. So I just also create the local variable `RET` to capture the exit code of the subshell before `local` succeeds and sets `$?` to zero.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `bash` evaluates this expression left to right?

Comment: As far as I am aware, variable assignments are in order, left to right in this context, yes.

Comment: @MaxRied the fact this works reliably would appear to indicate that yes, it is. However, I can find no information about this neither from POSIX nor `bash`'s reference manual.

Comment: As an aside, using all-caps variable names is bad form. See the POSIX environment variable spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, which describes all-upper-case names as reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or system and names with at least one lower-case character reserved for application-defined use, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace (since, in the event of collisions, assigning to the former can override the latter).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39490/discussion-on-answer-by-dopeghoti-how-to-make-local-capture-the-exit-code).

Answer (score 32):

Declare the local variable before you assign to it:

```
thing() {
  local output
  output="$(bash "${1##*/}")"
  echo "$?"
}
```

In my opinion this is also more readable than setting an additional `RET` variable.  YMMV on that, but it works just as you would expect.

Comment: This is *much* better than using a separate variable, as should be obvious if you want to check the return code of multiple assignments: simply `local var1 var2 ...` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @l0b0 Bob *is* my uncle. :D