# Command that may return error code in .bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc

I would like to set a variable inside `.bashrc` to be equal to the output of a command that may return an error code.

I do not know the implications of doing such a thing. Will everything else work correctly even if this command fails?

The code in `.bashrc` currently is simply:

```
export MYVAR=$(my_dubious_command 2>/dev/null)
```

Is it safe to do this?

Comment: If you want to be sure that an uncaught error won't cause a problem, add ` || :` to the end of the commandline to eat any potentially thrown error.  For instance, `myvar="$(/bin/false 2>/dev/null)" || :`.  This will also work in scripts in which `set -e` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As l0b0 [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370249/117549), it's unlikely that your .bashrc would be running with `errexit` set, but you could take care of that situation by testing:

```
case $SHELLOPTS in
  (*errexit*)   set +e;
                export MYVAR=$(my_dubious_command 2>/dev/null);
                set -e
                ;;
  (*)           export MYVAR=$(my_dubious_command 2>/dev/null)
                ;;
esac
```

The `export` command, as written, should return 0, in case any subsequent commands check `$?`; you are not providing any invalid options to it, the variable name is a valid one, and you are not exporting a non-existent function.

The case statement checks to see if `errexit` is set; if so, it temporarily turns it off in order to run `my_dubious_command`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
$ var=$(false)
$ echo $?
1
$
```

However, it is unlikely that you have `errexit` set in your .bashrc, and even less likely that the next command checks the exit code of your command, so it's very unlikely that it will affect anything.

Startup scripts like .bashrc are one place where you do *not* want to `set -o errexit`, because you can be blocked out of the shell by a simple typo or changes you are not in control of. To detect but not fail because of errors you can for example trap them:

```
$ trap 'echo $?' ERR
$ var=$(false)
1
$
```

This is quite useful in the [prompt](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/2217b4e8d8111cba3be4f698bffd6e2da3effc4f/.bashrc#L58-L60), for example.

Comment: By the way, I am using export (sorry I didn't write it clearly in my question). It seems export swallows the error code; I don't know if the question is still valid.

Comment: Yes, `export` does swallow the exit code. There can only be one exit code per command, and in that case `export` throws the command exit code away and returns its own.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera, you may also want to see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281749/135943